# MySQL View check if data is NULL

Tags: mysql, select, view, case, if-statement

I need to put a Case in the Select to check if the Data I'm adding to my view is NULL, in which case I want it to just enter a zero, or not.

Comment: I am confused. You can not, to my knowledge, add or update information in the database in a SELECT. Do you mean return `0`. And I am unsure what you mean by the 'or not' bit. Can you please provide some more information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
SELECT IF(`field` IS NULL, 0, `field`)...
```

There's also "IFNULL()":

```
SELECT IFNULL(`field`, 0)...
```

Comment: this is a classic case of misusing IF() and IFNULL() where the more generally accepted COALESCE() is a better idea.

Answer (score 7):

```
select coalesce(field, 0) as 'field' from v;
```

([doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce))

Answer (score 2):

When creating your table just add `NOT NULL` to the column description, e.g.

`CREATE TABLE (
ID INT NOT NULL default '0'
);`

Then if no data is given for the field it is set to the default value of 0 which will be retrieved when you run a SELECT query.

Comment: this doesn't apply if, for example, the NULL is the result of a LEFT OUTER JOIN.