# SELECT ORDER BY FIELD even if it doesnot exist

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
                    FROM  products2tecspecs as p2t, products_tecspecs as pt 
                    WHERE p2t.fk_product_id = '%s' AND pt.pts_id = fk_tecspec_id AND pt.pts_id 
                    IN (5275, 21, 5276, 5277, 5278,  49, 5279)
                    ORDER BY FIELD(pts_id, 5275, 21, 5276, 5277, 5278,  49, 5279)
```

I have this select, where I find de specific ID and bring it in the order I want.
But I have a problem with this relation. I am using it in a foreach function and I need the 7 loops. The problem isn't the null, the problem is that it brings only the relationed products. Of course it's not a problem, thank God it happens, but in my case it's destroy the layout if it comes only 2, for example.

Is there a way where I can do something like: If field not found, put this in place?

If I create the relation, it works, but I need to do it with 700 products...

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174850/mysql-view-check-if-data-is-null), but it doesn't seems to be an NULL problem...

I also tried with LEFT JOIN but as i said, if the relation doesnot exist it can not bring NULL...

I am blinded

---

I found this `SELECT pts_name
FROM (
SELECT pts_name,
CASE pts_id
WHEN 5275
THEN 1
WHEN 21
THEN 2
WHEN 5276
THEN 3
WHEN 5277
THEN 4
WHEN 5278
THEN 5
WHEN 49
THEN 6
WHEN 5279
THEN 7
END AS sort_order
FROM products_tecspecs
WHERE pts_id
IN ( 5275, 21, 5276, 5277, 5278, 49, 5279 )
)a
ORDER BY a.sort_order ASC`. It bring the SELECT I WANT, but still could not find a way to do my goal...

---

with join
    `SELECT *
    FROM products2tecspecs AS p2t
    LEFT JOIN products_tecspecs AS pt ON ( p2t.fk_tecspec_id = pt.pts_id )
    WHERE p2t.fk_product_id =34
AND pt.pts_id
IN ( 5275, 21, 5276, 5277, 5278, 49, 5279 ) OR p2t.p2t_value IS NULL 
ORDER BY FIELD( pts_id, 5275, 21, 5276, 5277, 5278, 49, 5279 )
LIMIT 40`

---

but did not work. it brought results beyond the `IN` fields selected.

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply add one of these options in your WHERE clause (with the LEFT JOIN solution):

```
    OR pt.pts_id IS NULL
    OR fk_tecspec_id IS NULL
```

?

Comment: As I posted, it did not work. Maybe with Case, or some IF but could not find how to...

Comment: In fact, is `p2t.p2t_value` that should be IS NULL, but did not work. tried `p2t.p2t_value=""`; Not worked either.